# Bitbucket and SSH "Permission denied"

Tags: git, bitbucket

I followed the instructions on the following page, https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action;jsessionid=426055AB68841447AC3CFFAD779D63AB.node3?pageId=270827678.

Added an SSH Public Key to my Bitbucket account successfully, yet I'm still getting the following message:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

What step am I missing? Thank you

Comment: Do you have your private key in your local SSH? For instance, my key is located at `~/.ssh/id_rsa`..other than that, I don't know enough about keys/certificates to help debug.

Comment: @Sam I have both keys saved in just .ssh folder, should I create and move it to "id_rsa" folder?

Comment: `id_rsa` is the file name of the key for me (not a directory, just extension-less).  Can you list the outputs of `ssh-add -l`?

Comment: Make sure you posted the content of your *public* key to bitbucket, not that of your *private* key. Having said that, I don't know if bitbucket can validate that.

Comment: @Sam Thank you for the help. I ended up deleting the keys I created and started from scratch. It seems to be working now.